# Is a network of non-validators really necessary?

Tags: stellar-core

From my understanding, stellar-core nodes (i.e., including watchers and validators) will arbitrarily connect to other nodes by default (i.e., no preferred peers set). 
While it makes sense for watcher nodes to connect to validators so they can propagate block/transaction, I cannot think of any reason to let my watcher node connects to another watcher node.

In other words, a peer-to-peer network of non-validator nodes seems to be unnecessary. If I want to catch up with the blockchain, I just directly go to one or more top validators. Why should I care about receiving blocks from other watcher nodes?

Answer (score 1):

There might be reasons for not being able to connect to your favorite validators (every validator has a maximum number of incoming connection slots, network outages, censorship...) altough yeah, I guess it's pretty unlikely to not being able to any node but watchers. However generally I'd say the more peers, the better the network resilience and data propagation. And as data transmission is kind of trustless, you basically don't need to care about the transmission path as long as blocks are verified/signed by your trusted validators.